# Pytorch: RuntimeError: result type Float can't be cast to the desired output type Long

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a model which looks as follows:

```py
IMG_WIDTH = IMG_HEIGHT = 224

class AlexNet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, output_dim):
    super(AlexNet, self).__init__()
    self._to_linear = None
    self.x = torch.randn(3, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT).view(-1, 3, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT)
    self.features = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(3, 64, 3, 2, 1), # in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding
        nn.MaxPool2d(2),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(64, 192, 3, padding=1),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True), 
        nn.Conv2d(192, 384, 3, padding=1),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True), 
        nn.Conv2d(384, 256, 3, padding=1),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(512, 256, 3, padding=1),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
  )
    self.conv(self.x)
    self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Dropout(.5),
        nn.Linear(self._to_linear, 4096),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Dropout(.5),
        nn.Linear(4096, 4096),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Linear(4096, output_dim),
    )

  def conv(self, x):
    x = self.features(x)
    if self._to_linear is None:
        self._to_linear = x.shape[1] * x.shape[2] * x.shape[3]
    return x

  def forward(self, x):
    x = self.conv(x)
    h = x.view(x.shape[0], -1)
    x = self.classifier(h)
    return x, h
```

Here is my optimizer and loss functions:

```py
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss().to(device)
```

Here is my `train` and `evaluate` functions:

```py
def train(model, iterator, optimizer, criterion, device):
  epoch_loss, epoch_acc = 0, 0
  model.train()
  for (x, y) in iterator:
    # features and labels to the device
    x = x.to(device)
    y = y.to(device).long()
    # Zero the gradients
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    y_pred, _ = model(x)
  
    # Calculate the loss and accuracy
    loss = criterion(y_pred.squeeze(), y)
    acc = binary_accuracy(y_pred, y)
    # Backward propagate
    loss.backward()
    # Update the weights
    optimizer.step()

    epoch_loss +=loss.item()
    epoch_acc += acc.item()

  return epoch_loss/len(iterator), epoch_acc/len(iterator)

def evaluate(model, iterator, criterion, device):
  epoch_loss, epoch_acc = 0, 0
  model.eval()
  with torch.no_grad():
    for (x, y) in iterator:
      x = x.to(device)
      y = y.to(device).long()
      y_pred, _ = model(x)
      loss = criterion(y_pred, y)
      acc = binary_accuracy(y_pred, y)

      epoch_loss += loss.item()
      epoch_acc += acc.item()
  return epoch_loss/len(iterator), epoch_acc/len(iterator)
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
RuntimeError: result type Float can't be cast to the desired output type Long
```

What may be possibly my problem because I have tried to convert my labels to `long` tensors as follows:

```
y = y.to(device).long()
```

But it seems not to work.

Comment: According to this post https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/multi-label-binary-classification-result-type-float-cant-be-cast-to-the-desired-output-type-long/117915 BCEWithLogitsLoss requires its target to have float32.

Comment: For me, just updating `Pytorch` version solved the problem. You would probably want to take a look at [here](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/8405) especially if you work with YOLO.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I was getting the same error doing this:

```
loss_fn(output, target)
```

where the ***output*** was Tensor **torch.float32** and ***target*** was Tensor **torch.int64**. What solved this problem was calling the loss function like this:

```
loss_fn(output, target.float())
```

Comment: I solved this by changing the datatype from long to float32, but that's basically the same.

Comment: Keep in mind that whenever your targets are tensors (i.e. of shape `(batch_size, num_classes)` for instance) always cast them as floats.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error while using a library (Huggingface). In that case you do not have access to the code that computes the loss. You do not convert the data type of your labels that you pass to the library. What worked for me was:

```
labels = labels.astype(np.float32).tolist()
```